# Using a HP headphone with microphone on a Mac Mini?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, microphone

Can anybody tell me how to use headphone with microphone on Mac Mini???

I have an HP Headphone (with microphone), I am able to connect headphone but the microphone does not appear to be working

Please tell me any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Standard headset microphones probably won't work with the Mac's microphone port. It only takes [line level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) input, whereas the microphone is producing a much weaker signal. This needs to be amplified before being input to the Mac.

The most common solution is just to get an external sound card (for instance, a [Griffin iMic](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/imic), which connects via USB) to connect your headphones.

Alternatively, most Macs come with a built-in microphone (although if one doesn't it'd be the Mac Mini). If you connect a pair of headphones, the internal microphone is useable for VoIP, at least in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your microphone is connected to the minijack input port.

Check your settings in "System Preferences" > "Sound". There should be a tab for selecting audio input devices, where you should be able to select "Line-in" as input source.